# Cards are drawn from a deck of 52 with replacement. In how many ways can ten cards be drawn so that the tenth card is not a repetition?

Tags: combinatorics

I am having trouble understanding the following problem:

> Cards are drawn from a deck of $52$ with replacement. In how many ways can ten cards be drawn so that the tenth card is not a repetition?

I had initially thought the solution was:

$$52^9 \cdot (52-9)$$ ...as the first $9$ cards can be anything and the $10$th cannot be the same as the first $9$.

However, I was told that this was incorrect and the solution I was given by my professor was:

$$52 \cdot 51^9$$

Please confirm that the solution given to me was correct and/or explain how it was calculated.

Thank you.

Comment: Start with the tenth card. There are 52 ways to draw the tenth card. How many ways can the other 9 cards be drawn?

Comment: The comment from Steven seems to be the correct approach. Your original answer is not quite right because it assumes that the first 9 cards were different, when in fact there could be repetitions.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment from @steven-gregory might be enough, but I'll elaborate a a little more. As @pbn990 pointed out, your original answer assumes that all the first 9 cards are different.

For simplicity, I'll write about the case of four cards:

> Cards are drawn from a deck of 52 with replacement. In how many ways can four cards be drawn so that the fourth card is not a repetition?

Your original approach would give the answer $52^3 \cdot (52-3) $. But that assumes that all the first three cards are the same. For example, assume these are the cards drawn:
Jack of Spades, Jack of Hearts, Jack of Spades, (??)

For the fourth card, there are NOT  $\; "52-3"$ options (cards) that fulfill the question's requirements, but instead there are $\; "52-2"$ options. You would have to subtract only two, because there are only two cards that would make the fourth a repetition: Jack of Spades and Jack of Hearts.

Now, the recommended solution implies starting counting (the number of ways) from the fourth card. You may wonder why you *can* start counting from the fourth card. That's because of two reasons:

1. Cards are drawn **with repetition**
2. Each card extraction is **independent** from all the others

Reason 2 is a consequence of reason 1.
For the calculation, the fourth card can be *any* card, so there are 52 ways of choosing it. And we know that the fourth card is *not a repetition*, so the third card *cannot* be the same as the fourth. Therefore, there are only $\; "52-1"$ cards to choose from. For the second card, it doesn't matter if it's the same as the third card. We only want the second card to be different from the *fourth* card, thus leaving us with $\; "52-1"$ cards that we can choose from if we want to fulfill the requirement. It's the same for the first card. And that gives us the final answer of
$$ 51^3 \cdot 52 $$